# Calculating slope from elevation returns hole when using ST_Slope in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, dem

I have rasters from the National Elevation Dataset loaded into a Postgres database and am using the built-in function `ST_Slope` to calculate the slope. However these contain many holes where there is valid elevation data.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpValues(ST_Slope(raster), ARRAY[1], False)).valarray as slope
FROM nat_elev_data
LIMIT 1;
```

I suspect that I need to pass additional parameters but am not sure what.

Comment: ST_Slope(raster, band, pixeltype) is the more common format. Perhaps you could post some data for the raster?

Comment: The NED data is publicly available. But to try to simplify things suppose I just had a single band raster with elevation in meters, could I just use `ST_Slope(raster)` or would I also need to specify `ST_Slope(raster, 1, '32BF')` to get valid slopes?

Comment: There are default values for most parameters. No substitute for just running it to see.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the function but why does it return so many holes?

Comment: I don't know without knowing what area you are looking at. Is there any way you can put a sample of your area as a gist on github or similar. Also, what is the value of ARRAY[1] above?